# Interfacing dot-matrix printer to embedded CPU

Tags: c, embedded

I want to interface any 80 column dot-matrix printer with my embedded device developed by LPC1768 arm controller with my own tiny kernel. I need driver information for this.

Comment: I suggest you look for a technical reference manual or something similar for your printer. I've found drivers are not as common in the embedded field as they are for desktop/server systems.

Comment: there is probably not a lot to it, and probably plenty of info either in linux drivers or just by googling.  your microcontroller is as powerful as the old pcs that used to drive the old dot matrix printers, if nothing else sniff the parallel port by putting a microcontroller or something in between a computer that knows how to talk to it and the printer.

Comment: Do a search on "Centronics protocol"; that's the commonly-used term for the handshaking sequence used to communicate with an old-fashioned parallel-port printer (by "old-fashioned" I mean a printer that takes plain character data and prints it, rather than one that expects an OS (generally Windows) to render the character data as graphics beforehand).

Comment: What type of interface does the printer have?  Centronics, RS232, ???

Answer (score 3):

Most dot-matrix impact printers use either RS-232 or Centronics/[IEEE 1284](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284) parallel port (some may support both).  So if you truly need to support *"any 80 column dot-matrix printer"*, then you will need to support both these in hardware.

These printers will generally accept plain ASCII text and control characters without any special driver or configuration.  However if you need to use special features such as [NLQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLQ#Near_Letter_Quality_.28NLQ.29), italics, bold, condensed, and graphics, then you will need to know the command language of the specific printer, of which there are several mostly manufacturer specific, so a different driver for each printer or printer language to be supported will be required. A common printer language that will allow support for a wide range of printers is [ESC/P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P).